# LinkText is not working in tree layout d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg, tree, data-visualization

I am trying to put linkText for the link in tree layout d3js but it is not wlrking, created the jsfiddle project [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/1v3rz0fw/6/). Can anybody let me know, why the linkText is not coming.

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.target.id;
            });
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function (d) {
    var o = {
        x : source.x0,
        y : source.y0
    };
    return diagonal({
        source : o,
        target : o
    });
});

link.transition().duration(duration)
.style("stroke", function (d) {
    return "#99FFCC";
})
.attr("d", diagonal);
link.append("text")
.attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
.attr("fill", "Black")
.style("font", "normal 12px Arial").attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" +
        (d.target.y - 50) + "," + 
        (d.target.x - 10) + ")";
}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function (d) {
alert(d.target.label);
return d.target.label;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in here:

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
.attr("class", "link")
...
...
link.append("text")
.attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
.attr("fill", "Black")
```

This code will put the text within the path DOM, which is incorrect.
Text DOM should never be within the path DOM.

Correct code should have been this:

```
// Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links);
    //adding the text to the svg
link.enter().insert("text")
        .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .attr("fill", "Black")
        .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
         .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + (d.target.y - 30) + "," + (d.target.x - 10) + ")";
            })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        console.log(d.target.label);
        return d.target.label;
    });
```

Full working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/451ko25p/6/).

Comment: For Link for your full working code - LinkText is coming fine but on click of parent node, node exit calls to the child node is exiting the node and nodeText but linkText remains there. LinkText should also exits on click of parent node.

Comment: You can do something like select all with class to remove all link _label..svg.selectAll(".line-label").remove();_
Updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/451ko25p/8/

Comment: Removing the link-label is working fine in only 1st label of tree layout. Even on click of the child node in 1st label all the linkText is deleted. On double click of child node also in 1st label, all the linkText is deleting from the other node's link. Only the clicked nodes link for its child is having the linkText.  Here is the jsfiddle project, you can see -  https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/s17bfwrh/2/

Comment: I am expecting some solution on link exit oparation, like node exit in the existing code